Sequence with complex numbers
Task:
Define $a_n=(b\cdot z)^n$, and $z=-1+i$. Find an expression for $|a_n|$ for all n $\in$ ℕ.
My solution:
Z can be expressed in polar form, as $\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{3pi}{4}i}$. Thus, I can find $|a_n|$:
$$|a_n| = (b\cdot z)^n = r^n |b|^n = \sqrt{2}^n|b|^n ,n \in ℕ $$
Would this be the correct way to solve it? I am almost certain I have made a mistake since it seems "far too easy". In particular, can I rewrite $(b\cdot z)^n$ to  $r^n |b|^n$? I welcome any critique with open arms!

$|a_n| = (b\cdot z)^n = r^n |b|^n = \sqrt{2}^n|b|^n ,n \in ℕ $ shoudl be $|a_n| = |(b\cdot z)|^n = r^n |b|^n = \sqrt{2}^n|b|^n ,n \in ℕ $. Otherwise, what you have done is fine.

Yes, that was a glaring mistake, of course I have to keep the absolute value throughout the equation!
